# Microsoft Excel lining up time values from different data sets

Tags: excel, graph, excel-formula, dataset, excel-2010

I am not an expert when it comes to using Excel and Excel functions so any help would be greatly appreciated. I have 2 different data sets which have different time intervals which I would like to show on the same graph. A sample from the 2 data sets is the following: (A1:B14 is the first data set, D1:E14 is the second data set)

[image]

As you can see, the time values from the different data sets do not line up with one another (second data set contains some missing seconds) and this is causing a problem when it comes to displaying the Memory and CPU values on the same time axis (which would be the x-axis in this case). If there an efficient way to display both the CPU and Memory values on the same time axis in such a case? And if so what is the best way to do this?

P.S: It is important that no data is removed in the process of lining up the data.

Thank you

Comment: I may have a quick solution for your other question that was just deleted, if you're still interested

Comment: Yes please. Any help will be greatly appreciated. @ashleedawg

Comment: I think I could make use of knowing that information somehow, yes. @ashleedawg

Comment: alright, well for lack of anywhere else to put it, I guess I'll post it as an answer to this question.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I appreciate it a lot. @ashleedawg

Answer (score 1):

This is only "related" to THIS question (not an answer), but you might find some value in it... (especially the links at the bottom!)

When working with times, there are various ways that you might be able to benefit from a list of "every second in a day", such as if you had a list of times and you need to figure out which ones are missing:

1. make a blank worksheet
2. highlight `Column A` by clicking the heading
3. hit `CTRL+1`, click `TIME` and choose a time format that includes seconds
4. now in cell `A1`, enter: `00:00:01`
5. in cell `A2` type: `=A1+$A$1`
6. click once on cell `A2` and hit `CTRL+C` to copy
7. hit `F5` and type: `A2:A86400` and hit Enter
8. hit `CTRL+V` to paste
   (now you have a list of every second in a day)
9. copy and paste this formula into cell `B1` (replacing both `(Range with your times)` with the the [single-column] range of cells where your time are, using **absolute cell references** (4 dollar signs) ie., if your times are in `column D` from `Rows 10 to 100` you would enter: `$D$10:$D$100`:

   ```
   =IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(  (Range with your times)  ,1,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP(A1,  {  (Range with your times)  ,1,FALSE))
   ```
10. click once on cell `B1` and hit `CTRL+C` to copy
11. hit `F5` and type: `B2:B86400` and hit `Enter`
12. hit `CTRL+V` to paste

Now `column B` will be blank for missing times, and show the times that are in your list.

if it doesn't work, go through the steps again, carefully.  Like anything with Excel or coding, details matter.  (For example, don't paste the formula into cell A1, and also your times must be in one single column, and the *absolute references* need to be properly specified in part of the formula or so it keeps referring to the same cells when you copy the formula.)

---

### **Recommended Tutorials**:

**Excel:**

- [Learnfree.org Excel 2016 Tutorial](https://www.gcflearnfree.org/excel2016/)

  - [Lifewire: Excel Step by Step Basic Tutorial](https://www.lifewire.com/excel-step-by-step-basic-tutorial-3123501)

**VBA:**

- [Excel VBA For Complete Beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.org/)
- MSDN (Microsoft Developer's Network) : [Getting Started with VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737(v=office.14).aspx)

Also: [Free month of training from LinkedIn](https://learning.linkedin.com/in/office?trk=par_acq_MSFThelp-all-tc-homepage-feature-feature-feature_learning&src=mi-inprod&veh=general-office-help&utm_source=microsoft&utm_medium=help-integration&utm_campaign=par_acq_MSFThelp-all-tc-homepage-feature-feature-feature_learning) in partnership w/ Microsoft

Comment: Thank you very much for this :) I appreciate all your help, will definitely try this out.

Comment: Glad to help.  Check out the links at the bottom of the answer (above) too.  There are a lot of crap tutorials out there (stay away from anything trying to sell you a book, which is half of them) but these ones seem pretty good.  Also, [so] is great but not so much for beginners.  You may find value (and less strict rules) at [Excel Guru](https://www.excelguru.ca/forums/) and  [Excel Forum](https://www.excelforum.com/) for the "more basic" questions.  Good luck, you'll figure it out.

Comment: Awesome :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into C2 then [double-click the fill handle](https://superuser.com/questions/859501/fill-formulas-until-end-of-adjacent-table/859580#859580).

```
=INDEX(E:E, MATCH(A2, D:D, 0))
```

Leave the #N/A errors. These are discarded in chart data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. However, forgot to mention that no data must be removed when lining up the data. I have edited the question accordingly.